# Is it possible to compute an object's checksum from within Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Basically all I want to do is run `sha1sum my-bucket/my-object` so that I can compare the object's digest to the digest of a copy of the object stored on my local drive.

`gsutil` doesn't appear to be able to do this, and from reading all of Google's docs, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to do this.

Am I missing something? Would I have to run a VM in Compute Engine and access the object that way?

I'm not very familiar with Google's platform so forgive me if this is a silly question. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

`gsutil hash your-local-file` will compute MD5 and CRC32C hashes of your local file.

You can then compare those with the hash(es) of your cloud object, which you can view by running `gsutil stat gs://your-bucket/your-object`.

Google Cloud Storage doesn't store SHA hashes of object data, but all GCS objects have a CRC32C checksum available in their metadata and many objects also have an MD5 hash - see [Hashes and ETags](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags)  for more information.

Comment: But in my view the hash value is worthless if it's "old" and from when the object was uploaded. To make a trustworthy consistency check you need a recalculated and current hash value of the object to tell if data has been corrupted on the cloud storage. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage performs internal consistency checks to prevent data corruption and ensure that the data always matches the hash.

Answer (score 3):

GCS won't compute a SHA1 hash for you, but you can certainly do it within the greater Google Cloud Platform. For example, you could start up a GCE instance, then use gsutil to stream the object into a SHA1 computation.

From a GCE instance, here's a command to produce a SHA1 sum of an object:

```
gsutil cat gs://bucket_name/object_name | sha1sum
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, If I want calculate the checksum of all files in a directory on GCS bucket, what should I do?

Comment: Depends what you mean. If you have several objects which could be concatenated into a larger file and you want to know the CRC32C of that file, you can calculate that from the individual CRC32C hashes. On the other hand, if you want a hash of a tree of objects, GCS doesn't offer any direct support for that. You could do it yourself by taking the list of object names and object hashes and hashing that, though.

Comment: Cloud build has created an artifact.json with a MD5 hash in it: {"location":"gs://xxxx","file_hash":[{"file_hash":[{"type":2,"value":"QmJ5R3NTTjExeVlZYUprTFhyWG9Ddz09"}]}]} is there any easy way to access that onFinalise?